# 'while read line do' cause: "syntax error near unexpected token `done'" in Linux bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, newlines

I have a shell script which is running fine on Solaris platform but not working on Linux platform. The Failing code snippet is as following:

```
[...]
while read line
do
insert_into_table="insert into isam_subrack_tbl (select neId, friendlyName, eqptHolderActualType from $line)"
$MYSQL_HOME/bin/mysql --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PWD  --host $MYSQL_HOST -Demlplatform -e "$insert_into_table"
done  < isam_subrack2.txt 2> /dev/null
[...]
```

When I run the script in debug mode:

```
bash-4.1$ sh -vvx test.sh
[...]
while read line
do
insert_into_table="insert into isam_subrack_tbl (select neId, friendlyName, eqptHolderActualType from $line)"
$MYSQL_HOME/bin/mysql --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PWD  --host $MYSQL_HOST -Demlplatform -e "$insert_into_table"
done  < isam_subrack2.txt 2> /dev/null
test.sh: line 98: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
'est.sh: line 98: `done  < isam_subrack2.txt 2> /dev/null
```

I tried `dos2unix` command but it did not help.
Do you have any idea about why I am getting this error in this while loop?

Comment: Chances are the problem is in the `[...]` part. The Bourne and Korn shell found on Solaris allow unmatched quotes especially backticks for instance (while other shells are stricter on that). Try with only -x to see where it first stops to make sense. Above we don't see the PS4 (xtrace) output.

Comment: Again the problem seems to be at 98th line:
bash-4.1$ sh -x ./cibi_linux.sh 
./cibi_linux.sh: line 98: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
'/cibi_linux.sh: line 98: `done  < isam_subrack2.txt 2> /dev/null

Comment: What does `file test.sh` say? It looks like evn after `dos2unix` you have `CR` line endings.

Comment: Sorry, I typed the cloned script's name. When running the test.sh:
`sh -x ./test.sh 
./test.sh: line 98: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
'/est.sh: line 98: `done  < isam_subrack2.txt 2> /dev/null`

Comment: @Murat, just like Stephane mentioned, the problem seems to be in the [...]. Hope the file for example with vim and enable the syntax check. You should be able to see if something is not terminated. I have my share of cases where the script complain at line 150 and the problem as on a misquote in a completed different line.

Comment: @Murat: check your file: `cat --show-nonprinting file`

Comment: Just copy your code an paste it here http://www.shellcheck.net/.

Comment: @Murat Don't get confused with the output error pointing to line 98. It just means where the shell becomes aware of the problem, not necessarily where it is.

Comment: It might well be that you have a missing / excessive single / double quote somewhere before the snippet. Otherwise one of `$MYSQL_HOME` `$MYSQL_USER`, `$MYSQL_PWD` and `$MYSQL_HOST` might contain one. A good start would be to enclose all of those in souble quotes and then as suggested by User112638726 to paste the whole script to shellcheck.net to check where the actual issue is.

Comment: I do hope you can guarantee the format of your source data file. Preferably before [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) comes round to play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a clue to the problem:

> ```
> test.sh: line 98: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
> 'est.sh: line 98: `done  < isam_subrack2.txt 2> /dev/null
> ```

That second line would normally read like this

```
test.sh: line 98: `done  < isam_subrack2.txt 2> /dev/null'
```

As you can see, the trailing quote mark from the error message is at the beginning of the line. This is symptomatic of unexpected CR characters in the text file. I see that you have run the file through `dos2unix` but I would still recommend you run it through something similar once more:

```
tr -d '\015' < src.sh > dst.sh
```

Comment: Thanks @roaima. This command made the script run correctly.

Comment: This is symptomatic of unexpected CR characters in the text file. +1